# Chrome can't load image, other browser can

Tags: google-chrome

**Image can't loaded** when I visit https://wangz.online/2019/06/19/16.html by **Chrome**. It worked by Microsoft Edge.[image]

And I found Chrome load image use **https** [image]

But the `src` should be **http**[image]

Comment: Chrome blocks mixed content.  https://www.howtogeek.com/443032/what-is-mixed-content-and-why-is-chrome-blocking-it/

Comment: @user2740650 Thanks, you solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Working fine here on linux: `Chrome Version 83.0.4103.116 (Official Build) (64-bit)` You can try to check if it's your version as well. It also may be a problem, [report](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en&ref_topic=7439544) that.